# Is every infinite set equipotent to a field?

Tags: field-theory, infinite-groups

For example, $\mathbb N$ is equipotent to $\mathbb Q$ which is a field.

$\mathbb R$ is equipotent to itself, which is a field.

But what about $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$, $P(\mathbb R^{\mathbb R})$ etc.?

Comment: Well, $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ is equipotent to $\Bbb R$, so perhaps that's a bad example.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks

Comment: Also, tip for LaTeXing: `\Bbb R` gives you $\Bbb R$

Comment: Or what about $\aleph_1$, which is the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals?  (If $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$ as Cantor conjectured and as was later shown to be a question not answered by the usual axioms, then the answer is clear, but can you explicitly make the set of all countable ordinals into a field somehow?) $\qquad$

Comment: Relevant: [Fields of arbitrary cardinality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296889/fields-of-arbitrary-cardinality).

Comment: @MichaelHardy it's things like this that make me realize how nice assuming the continuum hypothesis can be for sanity

Comment: @MichaelHardy Well, yes. Consider $\mathbb Q (\omega_1)$.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296889/fields-of-arbitrary-cardinality/1296910#1296910) is in some ways better than any relying on the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem, since it gives an explicit construction of a field of arbitrary infinite cardinality. $\qquad$

Comment: @Stefan : What do you mean by $\mathbb Q(\omega_1)$? Usually $\mathbb Q(x)$ means the smallest field that includes $\mathbb Q$ and contains some additional element called $x$, so it's essentially the field of all rational functions of $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$.  But that can't be what you mean. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy By $\mathbb Q(\omega_1)$ I mean the quotient field of the polynomial ring $\mathbb Q[X_\alpha \mid \alpha < \omega_1]$ with $\omega_1$ many variables.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: If you like niceness, then how about assuming $V=L$? It solves lots of problems, and you can always 'justify' your assumption by saying that no one can ever describe a set that isn't in $L$, so every universally quantified statement that you prove using your assumption really applies to every set that anyone can give you.

Comment: @user21820 I can describe many set that are not in $L$... (Obviously I can't prove their existence in $\operatorname{ZFC}$ - unless I can prove its inconsistency.)

Comment: @Stefan: Let me rephrase my statement. Nobody can ever describe **in ZFC** a set that isn't in $L$. To be completely precise, there is no first-order definable object over ZFC that can be proven to be not in $L$. Since ZFC is supposed to be the foundation theory, it does not make much sense to say that one can describe a set that isn't in L if one cannot prove **in ZFC** that such a set even exists. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it true that for any infinite set $E$, the cardinal of the field $\mathbb Q(E)$ is equal to the cardinal of $E$?

**added**
What is $\mathbb Q(E)$?
Here $E$ is considered to be a set of "indeterminates".  Or, if that is not convenient, invent a set of indeterminates perhaps with some notation like $X_e$, one for each element $e \in E$.  Then $\mathbb Q[E]$ is the set of polynomials in these indeterminates, with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$.  (Of course each polynomial involves only finitely many of the elements of $E$.)

So $\mathbb Q(E)$ is a ring.  It is an algebra over $\mathbb Q$.  It is an integral domain.

And $\mathbb Q(E)$ is the set of rational functions in these indeterminates.  In other words, formulas of the type $f/g$, where $f,g \in \mathbb Q[E]$ and $g \ne 0$.

So $\mathbb Q(E)$ is a field.  It has the set $E$ (or a set $\{X_e : e \in E\}$ identified with $E$) of mutually algebraically independent elements that generate it (as a field over $\mathbb Q$).

To compute the cardinality of $\mathbb Q(E)$, compute in turn: how many monomials in $E$ are there; how many linear combinations of monomials (i.e. polynomials); how many quotients of those (rational functions).

Comment: My first reaction was to downvote and flag to delete as "not an answer" (fortunately I withheld both in time). I don't think phrasing your answers as questions is a good idea...

Comment: I think your answer can be phrased in a "non-rhetorical" fashion.

Comment: Plus: easier than the L-S theorem.

Comment: A remark: This theorem relies on the axiom of choice (in this case, in the cardinal arithmetic needed to establish $|\Bbb Q(E)|=|E|$), and is in fact equivalent to the axiom of choice, since it implies the related theorem that [every set is equipotent to a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_structure_and_the_axiom_of_choice).

Comment: So you are saying that not only this proof, but the result itself is equivalent to AC.

Comment: @GEdgar Excuse me, what is ℚ(E) exactly? Link to an article about it?

Answer (score 7):

The field axioms are a countable set over a countable language. Since there is an infinite model of the field axioms, there is (by Lowenheim-Skolem) a model of every infinite cardinality.

Comment: Note that the cardinal arithmetic required here is the same as that required in GEdgar's (Gregory Grant's) answer, since one can easily see that the size of the model built by adding $κ$ new constants axiomatized to be all distinct is going to be between $κ$ and $|\mathbb{Q}| \cdot κ$.

Answer (score 3):

For every infinite set $X$ there is a field $\mathbb F$ which is equipotent to $X$. In fact, much more is true. This is an immediate consequence of the Upward [Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem). Fix a countable field $K$ (e.g. $\mathbb Q$). By the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem there is some $\mathbb F$ such that $\mathbb F$ is equipotent to $X$ and $K \prec \mathbb F$. This implies that $K$ and $\mathbb F$ have the same theory and since $K$ is a field, $\mathbb F$ is a field as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296889/fields-of-arbitrary-cardinality/1296910#1296910) by Gregory Grant is in some ways better than any relying on the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem, since it gives an explicit construction of a field of arbitrary infinite cardinality.

Comment: Since this link refers to a post on math.stackexchange, I don't think that the "This is a link-only answer" argument for closure applies as it will (most likely) remain accessible.